# Same-page links not working when used in Skeleton

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I searched SO and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443625/same-page-anchor-links-to-section-ids-not-working-in-ie8) but it only mentioned problems with IE8. I am having this problem in all browsers including Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 and Firefox 27.0.1.

My first step was to make sure my HTML was correct,

**Link**

```
<a href="#Submit-Testimonial" title="Submit Your Testimonial" class="button">Click Here to Submit Your Testimonial</a>
```

**Target**

```
<div name="Submit-Testimonial" id="Submit-Testimonial">
```

I used this code outside of frameworks and also with Foundation, and it always worked fine.

I thought it might be the way I set up my files in my project but even on [this demo](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bqmkn) where I link to Skeleton via CDN, I still have this problem. so I am led to believe that there is a problem being caused by Skeleton.

EDIT: 
A user suggested that I look into the `button` class to see if there could be a conflict caused by it. When I removed the button class, the problem still existed that the page would not redirect down to the target. Here is the CSS

/* #Buttons
================================================== */

```
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
    background: #eee; /* Old browsers */
    background: #eee -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: #eee -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.2))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: #eee -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: #eee -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: #eee -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: #eee linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%); /* W3C */
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover {
    color: #222;
    background: #ddd; /* Old browsers */
    background: #ddd -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: #ddd -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.3)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.3))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: #ddd -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: #ddd -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: #ddd -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: #ddd linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%); /* W3C */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa; }

.button:active,
button:active,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="button"]:active {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: #ccc; /* Old browsers */
    background: #ccc -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%, rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: #ccc -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.35)), color-stop(100%,rgba(10,10,10,.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: #ccc -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: #ccc -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: #ccc -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: #ccc linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.35) 0%,rgba(10,10,10,.4) 100%); /* W3C */ }

.button.full-width,
button.full-width,
input[type="submit"].full-width,
input[type="reset"].full-width,
input[type="button"].full-width {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    text-align: center; }

/* Fix for odd Mozilla border & padding issues */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's something in the CSS that is preventing it from navigating to the tag.  Did you look at the styles for the anchor and the class "button"?

Comment: @RickS great question. I removed the class to test, but the problem still exists.